# Use grunt to generate a single, static html page from several mustache partial templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, mustache, partial

I have a nodejs single page application that uses several mustache partial templates. I'm actually not using mustache for populating data, just for stitching together snippets of HTML into a single HTML file. I've tried using the [grunt-mustache-render](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-mustache-render) plugin to render my index.mustache template and all the partials into a single, static html file but the partials are not getting pulled in. A couple important notes: not all the partials are in the same directory, and some partials pull in other partials (zoinks!!!). And my templates are not those fancy <script type="text/template">, just straight up HTML (I switched to knockout data-bindings in case you're wondering why). The following is creating the build/index.html but none of the partial templates are getting inserted into the html. Am I even using the right grunt plugin? Is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated! TIA!

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')        
    mustache_render: {
      options: {
        directory: [
          'app/header/header.mustache', //header will pull in app/user/user.mustache
          'app/footer/footer.mustache'
        ]
    },
    your_target: {
      options: {
        directory: [
          'app/header/header.mustache',
          'app/footer/footer.mustache'
        ]
      },
      files : [
        {        
            data: 'data/properties.json',
            template: 'app/index/index.mustache',
            dest: 'build/index.html'
        }]
      },
    }
  });

grunt.registerTask('default', ['mustache_render']);

};
```

app/index/index.mustache

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mustache Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">

    {{> app/header/header.mustache}}

    <div class="content">some content would probably go here in a real example.</div>

    {{> app/index/footer/footer.mustache}}
  </div><!-- /#container -->
</body>
</html>
```

app/header/header.mustache

```
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="logo.png" />
  {{> app/user/user.mustache }}
</header>
```

app/user/user.mustache

```
<div class="user">
logged in as <a href="/profile">snotmonkey</a> | <a href="/logout">logout</a>
</div>
```

app/footer/footer.mustache

```
<footer>
  &copy; 2014 Snotmonkey Corporation
</footer>
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?